# Listing All Emails in Inbox by Outlook Web Addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am able to get details of previewed email by this JavaScript command:

`console.log(Office.context.mailbox.item);`

But I need to list all emails in the inbox (not only previewed one) by using Office JS, is it possible, if so how can I do it? (Its also okay receiving details from specified ID or e-mail number, if possible.)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's not possible with  Office.context.mailbox.item as it corresponds to a single item. To retrieve all the messages, use Graph API. Kindly refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thank you! So, how can I get my Bearer token for Graph API? I need to do it at client-side and I tried the code below but the output token is invalid: ```Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({isRest: true}, function(result){
  if (result.status === "succeeded") {
    var accessToken = result.value;

    // Use the access token.
    console.log(accessToken);
  }
});```

Comment: Have you tried to use yeoman generator to scaffold an add-in with SSO? Does it work correctly?

Comment: See [Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Office web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item in Outlook only. If you need to access other items in the user's mailbox I'd suggest using Graph API, see [Outlook mail API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) and [Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph) for more information.

Also you don't forget that VSTO based add-ins allows dealing with all items in Outlook stores. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .